# Can i please get an explanation to why this is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension (for fun) and i am trying to use a content script to inject a script into the web page, but this keeps tripping me up. I would like to understand if there is a difference here.

This doesn't work. I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')

```
var injectableScript = document.createElement("script")
injectableScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("requestwatch.js")
injectableScript.onload = function () {
    injectableScript.remove()
}
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(injectableScript)
```

Meanwhile on the contrary, this works:

```
var injectableScript = document.createElement("script")
injectableScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("requestwatch.js")
injectableScript.onload = function () {
    injectableScript.remove()
}
var targetElement = document.head || document.documentElement;
targetElement.appendChild(injectableScript)
```

Is there something i don't understand, by my knowledge this should be the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the parenthesis to encapsulate your conditional check for `head || documentElement` is causing the compiler to think you are trying to call  the `onload` function and chain call `appendChild` from the result. The error that's coming back is correct because `onload doesn't return a value`.

Basically it's reading your code like this:

```js
injectibleScript.onload = function() {
 ...
}(...).appendChild(...)
```

If you add a semicolon after the function declaration, then it'll work just fine.

Hope this helps!